# How to write for loop that returns string with java8 features?

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8, java-stream

Basically what I want to do is to write a for loop like below with java 8 features,

```
private String createHashCode() {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TRY; i++) {
        final String hashCode = createRandomString();
        if (!ishashCodeExistence(hashCode)) {
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
    throw new HashCodeCollisonException();
}
```

what I tried is ;

```
private String createHashCode() {
    IntStream.range(0, MAX_TRY).forEach($ -> {
        final String hashCode = createRandomString();
        if (!ishashCodeExistence(hashCode)) {
            return hashCode;
        }
    });
    throw new HashCodeCollisonException();
}
```

However, foreach method in lambda returns void so that I cannot return a string.

Is there any way to write my method instead of using normal for loop?

Comment: why do you need a forEach? Just use stream's filter

Comment: Use `map` followed by `findFirst`.

Comment: No need to have streams here: fast-exit `return` is as good as you know what.

Comment: The good old `for` loop looks perfect already.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how you *could* rewrite it with a stream if you really wanted to, although I personally prefer the good old `for` loop in this specific case:

```java
private String createHashCode() {
    return IntStream
            .range(0, MAX_TRY)
            .mapToObj(x -> createRandomString())
            .filter(hashCode -> !ishashCodeExistence(hashCode))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(HashCodeCollisonException::new);
}
```

Comment: Firstly, I really appreaciate for your comment, secondly, may I ask why you would prefer good old for loop in this case (asked just for get enlightened by your perspective)

Comment: `findAny` i.o. `findFirst` plus `.parallel()` would also be worth considering.

Comment: @YektaAnılAksoy I guess it's a matter of personal preference, but the `for` loop looks cleaner, easier to read. The "for if return" pattern is well known, there's no extra thinking when looking at the code. Streams can be useful tools when you need many operations like flat/map, filter, reduce, etc., but such simple cases aren't good candidates for them, IMHO.

Comment: @JoopEggen True, although that might end up with `createRandomString` being run more than needed if I'm not wrong (e.g. if `0` and `1` run in parallel while `0` succeeded already). It might not be an issue if `createRandomString` is cheap, but I tend to avoid parallel streams by default personally, unless profiling proved that parallelising would improve performances.

Comment: Agreed. Though this code looks like it is trying to find the perfect unique hash code - by brute force. Personally I would rather  find  the hash code with the least collisions.

Comment: @JoopEggen Actually, I get random string with RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(HASH_SIZE); and I look db whether it is already in db or not, if it is, I try up to 10 times to find a unique random otherwise throw exception. I use this for short url design. I couldnt find a way to produce 8 digits unique and random alphanumeric generator.